# Participe passé à valeur conditionnel

Tags: grammaire, usage, passé-composé, conditions

Comme on dit « (ayant été bien conseillé, il ferait mieux » ferait= conditionnel présent

Mais je vois que « ayant été ....» vient de « avait été... » ce qui est plus-que-parfait

Normalement, Si + plus-que-parfait+Conditionnel passé

Et donc est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ? Si c’est correct j’aimerais savoir pourquoi cette phrase ne s’écrit pas “ aurait fait”

Answer (score 2):

Les deux propositions sont correctes. Elles ne signifient pas la même chose:

Il n'est pas encore trop tard :

> *Ayant été bien conseillé, **il ferait mieux** de ne pas répondre à la provocation.*

L'action a déjà été effectuée :

> *Ayant été bien conseillé, **il aurait mieux fait** de ne pas répondre à la provocation.*